# How To Use Requests.py For Multi-accounts change pw?

Tags: python-requests

I have a website ....
(https://website.web/login)
which contain inputs #username & #password and #Login Button
after login
have link inside for password change...
(https://website.web/settings/password)
which contain inputs #old_password & #new_password & #confirm_password and #Submit Button
I have many account list #username & #passwords which set randomly
i wanna change all passwords with script i think with requests.py ?!
make #username = #password For all Accounts
Thanks

Comment: so you need help with hacking script ? :)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη actually No ain’t hacking bro i am administrator for a school and we will work on (Edmodo Website) i have many students in the shcool up to 2000 student i made account for them and it generated passwords for account randomly and i must print report for students #name #username #password #class_code so ! i wanna make username = password i change it manually and take long time so i back to programming as a help for this task cause programmers ask for much money if you can help thanks then if you cant modify comment to let others help thanku

Comment: idk which answer you are expecting without providing a [mcve]